# Unable to find element BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a specific href link from the following website: https://www.murray-intl.co.uk/en/literature-library.

Element i seek to parse:

```
<a class="btn btn--naked btn--icon-left btn--block focus-within" href="https://www.aberdeenstandard.com/docs?editionId=9123afa2-5318-4715-9783-e07d08e2e7cc&amp;_ga=2.12911351.1364356977.1629796255-1577053129.1629192717" target="blank">Portfolio Holding Summary<i class="material-icons btn__icon">library_books</i></a>
```

However, using BeautifulSoup I am unable to obtain the desired element, perhaps due to cookies acceptance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests as rq

page = requests.get('https://www.murray-intl.co.uk/en/literature-library')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find_all('a', class_='btn btn--naked btn--icon-left btn--block focus-within')
url = link[0].get('href')
url
```

I am still new at BS4, and hope someone can help me on the right course.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct tags, remove `"focus-within"` class (it's added later by JavaScript):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.murray-intl.co.uk/en/literature-library"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all("a", class_="btn btn--naked btn--icon-left btn--block")
for u in links:
    print(u.get_text(strip=True), u.get("href", ""))
```

Prints:

```
...

Portfolio Holding Summarylibrary_books https://www.aberdeenstandard.com/docs?editionId=9123afa2-5318-4715-9783-e07d08e2e7cc

...
```

---

EDIT: To get only the specified link you can use for example CSS selector:

```py
link = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Portfolio Holding Summary")')
print(link["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.aberdeenstandard.com/docs?editionId=9123afa2-5318-4715-9783-e07d08e2e7cc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea, how I can specify that I only want that specific link?

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks!